# How do I create a query that takes two columns and filters by latest version each column A by the latest version number in column B?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables.

1. Holds different family names. Example: familyA, familyB, familyC, etc.
2. Holds available versions. Example: A01, A02, A03, etc.
3. List of filenames with foreign key reference to the other two tables. This has every combination that exists.  Example: familyA_A01, familyA_A02, familyB_A01, familyB_A02, familyB_A03 etc.

I need a query that will give me the latest A00 version from the third table.

Result would look like familyA_A02, familyB_A03.

Comment: Actual sample data (as `create table` and `insert` statements for easy importing into a test database) and expected results based on that would be nice.

Comment: think i found it.  SELECT table3.table1id, MAX(table3.table2id) from table3 group by table3.table1id

Comment: use simple joining.. then grouping by with the 3rd table's key column might help.. otherwise you should at least provide more schema of your tables , so it would be easier to understand your exact need

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the operator `LIKE`:

```
select columnname
from tablename
where columnname like '%\_A0%' escape '\'
```

The underscore `_` needs to be escaped because it is a wild char for the operator `LIKE`.
This query will return all values in the column `columnname` that conatain `_A0`